# Separating color components

Tags: c++, c, opencv

I am following [this](http://linuxconfig.org/use-opencv-to-separate-rgb-image-into-red-green-and-blue-components#h3-usage) post to find the colour components of an image. I thought I'll start with the red component and then proceed towards other components. The code that I have written is given below. I am not using Linux, I am using Windows.

```
#include <opencv\cv.h>
#include <opencv2\imgproc\imgproc.hpp>
#include <opencv2\highgui\highgui.hpp>
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>

using namespace std;
using namespace cv;

int main(int argc, char**argv)
{
    IplImage* image=cvLoadImage("C:/Users/Administrator/Desktop/sample.png",1);
    IplImage* red=cvCreateImage(cvSize(image->width, image->height), image->depth,image->nChannels);
    uchar *pImg =(uchar*)image->imageData;
    uchar *pRed=(uchar*)red->imageData;
    for(int i=0;i<image->height;i++)
    {
        for(int j=0;j<image->width;j++)
        {
            red=pImg[i*image->widthStep + j*image->nChannels + 2];
            pRed[i*image->widthStep + j*image->nChannels + 2]=red;
        }
    }
    namedWindow("Display",1);
    cvShowImage("Display",red);
    waitKey(0);
    return 0;
}
```

The lines

> red=pImg[i*image->widthStep + j*image->nChannels + 2];
>
> pRed[i*image->widthStep + j*image->nChannels + 2]=red;

are showing this error:

> A value of type uchar cannot be assigned to an entity of the type
>   IplImage

Where am I going wrong?

Comment: What will split() return? For example I have 2 squares in an image, one is red and the other one is blue. Now I want the output such that only red colour is visible. Will split() be able to do that? I genuinely have no idea about this function. Could you answer and give me an image which would give me the result?

Comment: Sorry, I removed the comment and gave an answer on how to split channels.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use C++:

```
cv::Mat myImage;
myImage=imread("myImage.jpg");
std::vector<cv::Mat> channels;
cv::split(myImage,channels);
imshow("Red Channel",channels[2]);
```

Comment: could you post the result too please? And thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

`red` is defined here:

`IplImage* red=cvCreateImage(`...

It looks like you just want an individual colour value, so you need to use a new variable (I named it `redValue` to make it less confusing)

```
    for(int j=0;j<image->width;j++)
    {
        uchar redValue=pImg[i*image->widthStep + j*image->nChannels + 2];
        pRed[i*image->widthStep + j*image->nChannels + 2]=redValue;
    }
```

Comment: make it `uchar redValue` instead to not confuse him if he wants to USE that value for anything and interpret the value. In addition if he isn't forced to use IplImage I would suggest him to switch to `cv::Mat` as soon as possible.

Comment: So how do I display the red component then?

Answer (score -1):

First: If you aren't forced to use `IplImage` please switch to `cv::Mat`because it's so much easier to use and understand the new c++ syntax of openCV!

For your problem: if you want to extract just the red channel (manually like you do it, openCV could do it with a function call for your), try this code: I've added comments where I changed something:

I use this as an input image for testing:

[image]

```
#include <opencv\cv.h>
#include <opencv2\imgproc\imgproc.hpp>
#include <opencv2\highgui\highgui.hpp>
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>

using namespace std;
using namespace cv;

int main(int argc, char**argv)
{
    IplImage* image=cvLoadImage("C:/Users/Administrator/Desktop/sample.png",1);
    // !!! the image that shall contain the red channel must have number of channels = 1 !!!
    IplImage* red=cvCreateImage(cvSize(image->width, image->height), image->depth,1);
    uchar *pImg =(uchar*)image->imageData;
    uchar *pRed=(uchar*)red->imageData;
    for(int i=0;i<image->height;i++)
    {
        for(int j=0;j<image->width;j++)
        {
            // !!! you have to use a variable that holds the value of single channel's pixel, which is uchar in this case (values from 0 to 255)
            uchar redVal=pImg[i*image->widthStep + j*image->nChannels + 2];
            // !!! since the red image has only 1 channel, be sure to use the right ->nChannels (from the 'red' image
            pRed[i*red->widthStep + j*red->nChannels]=redVal;
        }
    }
    namedWindow("Display",1);
    cvShowImage("Display",red);
    waitKey(0);
    return 0;
}
```

This should display just the red channel as a grayscale image.

The result looks like this for a lena input image:

[image]

If you want to display it in RGB and shut off the other channels try this:

```
#include <opencv\cv.h>
#include <opencv2\imgproc\imgproc.hpp>
#include <opencv2\highgui\highgui.hpp>
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>

using namespace std;
using namespace cv;

int main(int argc, char**argv)
{
    IplImage* image=cvLoadImage("C:/Users/Administrator/Desktop/sample.png",1);
    // !!! use 3 channels again because we want to display colors
    IplImage* red=cvCreateImage(cvSize(image->width, image->height), image->depth,3);
    uchar *pImg =(uchar*)image->imageData;
    uchar *pRed=(uchar*)red->imageData;
    for(int i=0;i<image->height;i++)
    {
        for(int j=0;j<image->width;j++)
        {
            // !!! you have to use a variable that holds the value of single channel's pixel, which is uchar in this case (values from 0 to 255)
            uchar redVal=pImg[i*image->widthStep + j*image->nChannels + 2];
            // !!! set all channels to zero, except the red channel which is copied. be sure to use the right widthStep 
            pRed[i*red->widthStep + j*red->nChannels + 0]=0;
            pRed[i*red->widthStep + j*red->nChannels + 1]=0;
            pRed[i*red->widthStep + j*red->nChannels + 2]=redVal;
        }
    }
    namedWindow("Display",1);
    cvShowImage("Display",red);
    waitKey(0);
    return 0;
}
```

The result looks like this for lena input image:

[image]

Comment: Unhandled exception at 0x000000013FA012F3 in Red.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation writing location 0x000000000046E000.

This is the error and the line that is responsible is:

pRed[i*image->widthStep + j*red->nChannels + 2]=redVal;

Are you sure about this program?

Comment: I edited it, `pRed[i*image->widthStep + j*red->nChannels + 2]=redVal;` was wrong because `image->widthStep` is obviously wrong when accessing elements of `red`. And since we've only one channel in the red image, the +2 was wrong too :). Had to edit it a second time! Can't test the code, but these two changes should do it I guess.

Comment: edited again if you don't want to extract the red channel but want to set the non-red-channels to zero

Comment: I got the red part in my live feed. Now I want to surround it. Like draw a rectangle around it. How to do that? I saw somewhere that someone using Moments had done something but I couldn't understand it. You have any idea about it?

Comment: ok, tested the code and it works. Added pictures of the results.
For your following rectangle detection problem I would use the first version (extracting just the red channel as a single channel image) and compute the threshold (which would be very easy with `cv::Mat syntax` but I guess the method `cvThreshold(...)` does exist, too. Then find the bounding box of all red pixels by checking each pixel that's not zero and remember their min/max x/y coordinates.

Comment: So for a real time application I should get the image, apply the threshold and then store its position. Now that I have stored the position I use the coordinates to draw a rectangle/circle/any other shape?

Comment: not sure what exactly you want to do, maybe you create another question because it's not so nice to answer this in comments. Remember to add input/sample images (and if possible an image that explains what you want to achieve).

Comment: So you know the answer :P

Comment: no, I'm really not sure what you want to achieve, I could try to find it out but thats quite painful in comments ;)

Comment: My question's the same.